# ACTION_BARCODE_SERVICE_BROADCAST intent in IONIC Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-intent, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app which runs on a PE900S scanner device.

My desire is to use the device native scanner to scan QR codes. The device is not equiped with a camera, so I cannot use phonegap-barcode-scanner plugin.

I have tried to manage this using Cordova-webintent plugin: https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent.

My plan is to run a function that opens the 'Complete action using' window, then select an app called getBarcode, which is insatlled on the device. The problem is that this app doesn't appear in that window.

This is my code:

```
 $scope.scan = function() {
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW
    },
        function(res) {
            alert(res);
        }, function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }    
    ); 
};
```

How can I make a certain app appear in that window? Or is there any other way I can scan with the native device?